# FMDB MODIFY query not working to set constraints in existing SQLite database

Tags: objective-c, database, sqlite, fmdb

My sqlite database has existing column named order_id in tbl_order with duplicate entries.
I am trying to remove duplicate entries and add constraint(UNIQUE) to solve this.

So I have tried following code to solve above issue.
I have checked previous and current build version to manage existing and new database.

It successfully executes first query but showing error in modify constraint.

```cpp
    if (previousBuildVersion < currentBuildVersion) {
        FMResultSet *result = nil;
        result = [self.objDB executeQuery:@"SELECT DISTINCT order_id FROM tbl_order ORDER BY order_id"];
        [self.objDB executeUpdate:@"ALTER TABLE 'tbl_order' MODIFY \ 'order_id' TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE \ ;"];
    }
```

I am getting this error in Xcode:

> [logging] near "MODIFY": syntax error
>
> DB Error: 1 "near "MODIFY": syntax error"

Please suggest a solution to this issue as I have very less experience working with FMDB library.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You cannot alter column in sqlite once it has been created.

Only the `RENAME TABLE` and `ADD COLUMN` variants of the `ALTER TABLE` command are supported. Other kinds of `ALTER TABLE` operations such as `DROP COLUMN, ALTER COLUMN, ADD CONSTRAINT,` and so forth are omitted.

Please check this link for more details :
https://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html